# How to accept user input in thesaurus api to display synonyms using flash as3

Tags: api, actionscript-3, flash, thesaurus

am working on a project to develop a thesaurus app using flash as3. However my app works fine but it only displays the synonym for the word already being put inside the thesaurus API url. However, I want my app to allow any user input through the input text field. Is there a way to do that? Many thanks in advance. I use "Big Huge Thesaurus API" for synonyms. For example in below API URL only synonyms for word "mother" are displayed.

"http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/958af28ac9e3b21c650cbdd24a2466e8/mother/"

Here is my full code.

```
button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadScores);
function loadScores(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var fileLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    fileLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, scoresLoadComplete);

    fileLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/958af28ac9e3b21c650cbdd24a2466e8/mother/"));

}

function scoresLoadComplete(evt:Event):void {
    try {

        var returnVars = evt.target.data;
        highscores.htmlText = returnVars;

        trace("Data retrieved successfully");
        for (var myVars in returnVars) {
            trace(myVars + ": " + returnVars[myVars]);
        }

        trace("***********************");

    } catch (err:Error) {
        trace("Can't parse loaded file: " + err.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, why don't you just replace the word `mother` with the user input text in your URLRequest?

Comment: @DodgerThud Can you show me a bit of code for your idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have an input text box in your application and set its instance name to "userinput" and change the following line in your code.

fileLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/958af28ac9e3b21c650cbdd24a2466e8/mother/"));

to

fileLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://words.bighugelabs.com/api/2/958af28ac9e3b21c650cbdd24a2466e8/**"+userinput.text+"**/"));

Comment: I put exactly like your code and it works fine. By then the idea is to display the word that you enter in the input field, to the output dynamic field, then display the synonyms for that word. Now, i can only display synonyms. So how to display that same word upon button click.? Thanks

Comment: you can add that same text in your synonyms list